# Screenshot of window with hardware accelerated rendering

Tags: winapi, gpu

I'm trying to get a screenshot of windows using PrintWindow. Windows using hardware rendering are not captured. For example Chrome, Edge. In Windows 7 they are captured, but in Windows 10, 11 they are no longer there. There is a suspicion that this is due to the version of WDDM. Is there any possibility:

- capture hardware rendering?
- disable hardware rendering for the whole system?
- Disable or otherwise affect WDDM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PrintWindow() could not print Google Chrome window (Chrome\_WidgetWin\_1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965343/printwindow-could-not-print-google-chrome-window-chrome-widgetwin-1)

Comment: Try using [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) instead. There's [interop support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.graphics.capture.interop/nf-windows-graphics-capture-interop-igraphicscaptureiteminterop-createforwindow) for native `HWND`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I 've made a simple capture library [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5256890/ScreenCapture-Single-Header-DirectX-Library). Code is [here](https://github.com/WindowsNT/ScreenCapture) and it's based on [Desktop Duplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api). Microsoft sample is [here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/DXGI%20desktop%20duplication%20sample). It uses hardware capturing.

My work primarily captures video with sound, but there is a frame callback you can use to capture a frame. Apparently it's the same API that is used to capture games etc.

Comment: Desktop Duplication doesn't allow you to take a screenshot of a window that's partially occluded, fully hidden, or minimized.